# Extracting only email body to file

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a VBA script that extracts incoming outlook email into `txt` files. Here's the code:

```
 ' General Declarations
Option Explicit

' Public declarations
Public Enum olSaveAsTypeEnum
  olSaveAsTxt = 0
  olSaveAsRTF = 1
  olSaveAsMsg = 3
End Enum

Sub Export_MailasMSG(item As Outlook.MailItem)
' Routine will take all selected mails and export them as .MSG files to the
' directory defined by
' Error Handling
On Error Resume Next

' Varaiable Declarations
Dim strExportFolder As String: strExportFolder = "C:\OutlookEmails\"
Dim strExportFileName As String
Dim strExportPath As String
Dim strReceivedTime As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim objRegex As Object

' Initiate regex search
Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegex
.Pattern = "(\s|\\|/|<|>|\|\|\?|:)"
.Global = True
.IgnoreCase = True
End With

    ' If the currently selected item is a mail item we can proceed
    If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        ' Format the file name
        strReceivedTime = item.ReceivedTime
        strSubject = item.Subject
        strExportFileName = Format(strReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                vbUseSystem) & Format(strReceivedTime, "-hhnnss", _
                vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & strSubject
        strExportFileName = objRegex.Replace(strExportFileName, "_")
        ' Export to the predefined folder.
        strExportPath = strExportFolder & strExportFileName & ".txt"
        item.SaveAs strExportPath, olSaveAsTxt
        ' MsgBox ("Email saved to: " & strExportPath)
    Else
        ' This is not an email item.
    End If



' Clear routine memory
Set item = Nothing
Set objRegex = Nothing

End Sub
```

The txt files I get are as follows:

```
From:   Name Surname <email@address.com
Sent:   mercoledì 17 gennaio 2018 12:16
To: email@email.com
Subject:    subject here

BODY HERE
```

Can I extract only the mail body, without the from, sent, to and subject lines?
If so, how can I achieve that? I don't know VBA programming.

I've tried changing this line  `"item.SaveAs strExportPath, olSaveAsTxt"` to `" item.Body.SaveAs strExportPath, olSaveAsTxt"` but with no luck.

Comment: In your code `item` is the entire MailItem.  If you save `item` you will get everything.  You access parts of a MailItem as `item.xxxx`.  For example, you access `item.ReceivedTime`.  You want to save `item.Body` for the text body or `item.HtmlBody` for the Html body.  `item.Body` and `item.HtmlBody` are strings so save as text files.

Comment: If you use `On Error Resume Next` like this, you mean: "Don't bother telling me about any problems because I like obscure failures."  To use it correctly, write `On Error Resume Next` `Single statement that might fail` `On Error GoTo 0` `Check Err` ... .  With your approach, any statement could fail and code execution would continue as those it had worked. With the recommended approach, you can provide bespoke error handling for selected statements.

Comment: In the previous comment, the penultimate sentence should be: "With your approach, any statement could fail and code execution would continue as *though* it had worked."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The simplest way to save just Email Body see example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Example()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.mailitem

    Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Email.txt", ForAppending, True)
        TS.Write (olMsg.Body)
        TS.Close

End Sub
```

*[See MSDN TextStream Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724(v=vs.60).aspx)*

Comment: Starting from your reply, I ended up using:

`Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim TS As TextStream
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TS = FSO.CreateTextFile(strExportPath, True)
TS.WriteLine (item.Body)
TS.Close`